# Problem in passing arrays from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++

I have an application in which I need to pass an array from C# to a C++ DLL. What is the best method to do it? I did some search on Internet and figured out that I need to pass the arrays from C# using ref. The code for the same:

```
status = IterateCL(ref input, ref output);
```

The input and output arrays are of length 20. and the corresponding code in C++ DLL is

```
IterateCL(int *&inArray, int *&outArray)
```

This works fine for once. But if I try to call the function from C# in a loop the second time, the input array in C# is showing up as an array of one element. Why is this happening and please help me how I can call this function iteratively from C#.

Thanks,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
[DllImport("your_dll")]
public extern void IterateCL([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] arr1, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] arr2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but try using `fixed`:

```
fixed (int* arr1 = new int[10], arr2 = new int[10])
{
            //acting with arr1 arr2 as you wish
}
```

Or you can use marshaling

```
[DllImport("your_dll")]
public extern void IterateCL([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] arr1, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] arr2);
```

Comment: @ILya: Yeap, it isn't necessary.

Comment: @abatishchev Why without OutAttribute? I thought we need to return a value from C++ to C# but InAttibute is only one direction.

Comment: As far as I understand from OP function declaration the first param is only In and the second - in Out. Though you can specify both attributes for both params but I guess it will be overuse

Comment: @abatishchev, Oh sure you are right! I have to read more carefully.