# C# passing double array to C++ dll

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll, parameter-passing

I have an array initialized in C# code; Then I am going to pass it to C++ dll in which each single entry of the array will be re-assigned with new value. Then the array with be returned back to C# with the new value.
I am wondering

1. what is the best way to pass the array from C# to C++? (Data structure of this array in C#)
2. What is the best way to return the array from C++? (Data structure of this array in C++)

My code is not working:

In C#

```
private static double[] _statsArray = new double[4];
GetImageStats( ref _statsArray);
```

In C++ dll:

```
DllExportImageStatistics GetImageStats( double (&pSignalArray)[4])
```

Thanks for any suggestions; A couple of lines of code will help a lot.

Comment: Show your managed prototype.

Comment: Is that the C# code I posted?

Comment: There is a descent article on passing arrays between managed and unmanged code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6.aspx and  same question has been asked sevral time, so those links may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406972/problem-in-passing-arrays-from-c-sharp-to-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340333/return-c-arrays-to-c-sharp etc

Comment: There should be a managed prototype that has a `[DllImport]` attribute in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
private static double[] _statsArray = new double[4];
GetImageStats(_statsArray); // Lose the ref
```

And

```
DllExportImageStatistics GetImageStats(double pSignalArray[4])
```