# how to copy an integer from C# method to native C DLL function

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-c++, dll

I want to pass an integer from C# method into native C DLL set_power(), but get run-time error:  "PInvokeStackImbalance" when C# calls the C function set_power().

C# declaration:

```
[DllImport("Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.dll")]
public static extern int set_power(int power_percent);
```

C# method:

```
int target_power_percent = 123;
int new_value = set_power(target_power_percent);   <<<<<<<<<<<<<  GETS ERROR
```

NATIVE C DLL FUNCTION:

```
__declspec(dllexport)  int   set_power( int power_percent  )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the type of `target_power_percent`?

Comment: what compiler errors do you get?

Comment: You can try what is here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339922/c-sharp-passing-double-array-to-c-dll, and change the double to int.

Comment: Aha. First, this is not a compiler error but a runtime error. Two completely different things. Second, you need to check the default calling convention your C compiler. CLR defaults to stdcall, but many C compilers default to cdecl and a mismatch will produce exactly the kind of runtime error you show.

Comment: Raj 42:  that did not work.

Comment: My Visual-C++ proj > Config Prop > C/C++ > Advanced > Calling Convention is blank, but its dropdown list has options: cdecl, stdcall, or fastcall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stdcall` on the native side.

Comment: I set Visual-C# project props > Config Props > C/C++ > Adv > Calling Conv: to stdcall and that fixed it

Comment: Set that on a per method basis. You have just wrecked the performance of lots of other unrelated methods. Don't use a global setting for a local problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`public static extern Int32 set_power(Int32 power_percent);`

Edit:

Oh, and:

```
[DllImport("Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```